# Element for a card/card-container in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, teaser

The specification for the `article` element says:

> The `article` element represents a component of a page that consists of
>   a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site
>   and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable,
>   e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an
>   interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of
>   content.

So, if I'm building a website where, in its home page, I have cards that are clickable and leads you to the article page, would be better - in semantic - if this card would be a `section` or an `article` element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be appropriate to use the `article` element for post teasers. It depends on what content you show. For example:

- **Yes**: If you show the title, a description, an image, the author name, and the publication date, you should definitely use the `article` element.
- **No**: If you only show the title, an `article` element wouldn’t be warranted, because each teaser would become an entry in the document outline (as `article` is a sectioning content element), but there isn’t much point for an outline entry if it doesn’t contain any additional content.
- **Maybe**: Something inbetween. Title and date? Probably not. Title and description? Probably yes.

If you decide to use `article` (and only then!), you can use the [`bookmark` link type](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#link-type-bookmark) for the link to the full article page. This can be a hint that your `article` isn’t the "full thing".

If you decide not to use `article`, don’t use `section`. If choosing between `article` and `section`, `article` is the correct choice for a teaser. But if `article` isn’t appropriate, you shouldn’t use another sectioning content element, but something like `p` and/or `ul` (and no heading elements).