# Which HTML5 tags are semantically correct to represent e-commerce products?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

[image]

Should I wrap the products with unordered list `<ul><li>`?

How can I make products clickable without JavaScript, just using HTML? Can I wrap each product with:

```html
      <a href="linkToProduct">
       <article>
         <h3>Product 1</h3>
         <img src="images/product1.png" alt="product 1">
         <p><data value="50">50</data>$</p>
      </article></a>
```

Here is my code :

```html
<section id="my-products">
      <h1>My Products</h1>
      <article>
        <h3>Product 1</h3>
        <img src="images/product1.png" alt="product 1">
        <p><data value="50">50</data>$</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Product 2</h3>
        <img src="images/product2.png" alt="product 2">
        <p><data value="130">130</data>$</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Nikon D7000</h3>
        <img src="images/product3.png" alt="product 3">
        <p><data value="56">56</data>$</p>
      </article>
</section>
```

Comment: OK thanks , are <figure, <figcaption> correct to represente each product with his title ??

Comment: Sounds more appropriate to me than `<article>`, yep

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `article` element is the correct choice for a product.

If you have a list of products, you may use the `ul` element, but [you don’t have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846292/1591669). Placing multiple `article` elements in a `section` element without a `ul` element is fine, too.

To make the whole content of the product clickable, you may wrap everything in an `a` element. But instead of using `<a><article></article></a>`, it might be better to use `<article><a></a></article>`, as [this allows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44013589/1591669) you to use the `bookmark` link type:

```html
<article>
  <a href="" rel="bookmark">
    <!-- … -->
  </a>
</article>
```

Comment: The `article` tag is not the right fit for this example, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845498/4814589)

Comment: @GhassenRjab: I don’t agree with that answer (as linked in my answer here, I also gave an answer to that question). If your product teaser has a heading, you should use a sectioning content element. As `nav` and `aside` are not appropriate, there is only `section` or `article`. A product teaser is still "self-contained" (you don’t need the context to make sense of it), so `article` is the more specific ("semantic") choice.

Comment: i agree with @unor <article> for independent content, stuff that can be removed from this website and would still be understandable, like blog posts & products.

Answer (score 1):

First, yes you need to use `<ul><li>` and wrap your products in `<a>` tags.

Second, in your case, you can use `<article>` to represent a product, and you can use as well the [itemtype](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs_universels/itemtype) attribute. And don't put `<h3>` without using `<h2>`.

So your code would look like so :

```
<section id="my-products">
  <h1>My Products</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="product_link">
        <article class="product-item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <h2 itemprop="name">Product 1</h2>
          <img src="images/product1.png" alt="product 1">
          <p><data value="50">50</data>$</p>
        </article>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="product_link">
        <article class="product-item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <h2 itemprop="name">Product 2</h2>
          <img src="images/product2.png" alt="product 2">
          <p><data value="130">130</data>$</p>
        </article>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="product_link">
        <article class="product-item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <h2 itemprop="name">Nikon D7000</h2>
          <img src="images/product3.png" alt="product 3">
          <p><data value="56">56</data>$</p>
        </article>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use `article` here? As you are using headings, you are creating implicit sections anyway, but it’s preferable to make sections explicit. So a sectioning content element should be used, and `article` is the appropriate choice here.

Comment: It is how I developed websites. I use `article` in the product details page and not in a listing containing a photo, a name and a price. That is not a full article. You can see other websites like [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/), [Balibart](https://www.balibart.com/en/) and [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/) none of them uses `article` tags when listing their products.

Comment: It doesn’t *have* to be the full content, as long as it is self-contained (e.g., could appear in a feed etc.). Of course there are cases where you don’t need a sectioning content element (e.g., if you only have the product name linked to the product page), but as soon as you are using heading elements (`h1`-`h6`), you *are* creating sections, and the HTML spec recommends to make sections explicit. Then you have the choice between `section` and `article`, and the case of a product (or product teaser) matches the definition of `article`.

Comment: I edited my answer to use `<article>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: Just wanted to address few misconceptions.

"And don't put <h3> without using <h2>" - This looks more like a personal opinion to me. It is OKAY to use an h3 without using h2. (The problem arises when both are used in the same sectioning content and h3 comes before h2)

"wrap your products in <a> tags." - That depends on the intent. Is it a list of links to products you are showing or a list of products.

Comment: @GhassenRjab according to teamtreehouse.com, "You shouldn't put block elements within inline elements because it breaks the element structure. Inline elements are meant to reside within block level elements so that they render correctly and follow the flow of content."