# Marking up product boxes in HTML5

Tags: html, product, semantic-markup

What would be semantically correct way of marking up products in HTML5?

This is how I do it currently. I am using BEM in the following example:

```
<div class="product__box">
  <h2 class="product__box-title"> 
    Chair
  </h2>
  <img class="product__box-img" src="but-can-it-do-this.jpeg" alt="image-of-chair">
  <p class="product__box-price>
    $399 
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="product__box-button role="button">
    Add To Cart 
  </a>
</div>
```

I saw some people using `<article>` tags instead of `<div>`, but I am not sure that is correct. This is the shortened definition from W3C:

> The `article` element (...) could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

How would you mark up a product to follow HTML5 spec?

Comment: Related: [Which HTML5 tags are semantically correct to represent e-commerce products?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46259821/1591669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much up for debate and depends on the general semantics of your website, but I think you could change the surrounding div with article in your example.

As the spec states:

> article
>
> Represents a section of a page that consists of a composition that
>   forms an independent part of a document, page, or site.

I'd argue a "product box" (a.k.a. teaser as far as I understand) is a "composition that forms an independent part"...

Some further reading about the article-tag and HTML5 semantics in general:

[html5doctor: Let's talk about semantics](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/)

[adactio.com: Pursuing semantic value](https://adactio.com/journal/4999/)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I will use the `<article>` it in the future.